# SaveChanges without AcceptChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Calling method `SaveChanges` in `DbContext` will call `SaveChanges` in `ObjectContext` with default save option `SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave`.

So, all changes will be accpeted after save.

I want to control it in manual mode:

1. Detect changes
2. Save changes
3. Accept changes

Now, 2 and 3 are united in one operation, so I can't to do some operations between 2 and 3. How can I divide it?

Comment: why not try `SaveChanges(false);` then `AcceptAllChanges(); `

Comment: @active92 `DbContext` has no method `SaveChanges(bool)`

Comment: Wouldn't you have to swap 2 and 3? I don't understand how you can accept (or reject) changes after you've already saved them.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to use `ObjectContext` methods directly (or create your own helper methods to do what you need).

Comment: How about wrapping the whole thing in a transaction? Depending on what you want to do it might be sufficient to execute additional code before `transaction.Commit()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I think, it's a solution

Comment: @Sentry no, in terms of EF `Save changes` means `write to database`, and `Accept changes` means `set entities as not modified`

Comment: @grek40 no, it's not about transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Ivan Stoev's comment:

```
internal sealed class TestContext : DbContext
{
    protected ObjectContext ObjectContext => ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        //detect all changes in context
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        //write changes to database
        var result = ObjectContext.SaveChanges(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.SaveOptions.None);

        //do some actions with entities
        DoStuff();

        //accept all changes in entities
        ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges();

        return result;
    }
```